# What this statement in qt c++ does?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm learning qt framework for c++ and I'm not able to understand what this statement does:

Window::Window **(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)**
{
....
}

// **(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)**  <---

Comment: Are you new to C++ as well?

Answer (score 1):

This statement means calling base class constructor. In your context it is widget class. It is base class for window. Actually parent widget will be passed to this constructor